# How to update the clang version to compile a C++11 project? (on Mac)

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, clang

I'm trying to build a project which is originally written for archlinux. The building process works fine on that archlinux but has a huge amount of errors when I tried to build it on my mac. The project is basically written in C++11 so it's very unstable. I think there has something to do with the compiler because the clang version in mac is 4.2(It actually shows **'Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)'** when I type **clang --version**) and 3.3 for linux. So I want a different version of clang, perhaps 3.3. How Can I specify the version of my compiler when trying to build the project?

Comment: There is no `clang` 4.5 version. Are you talking about XCode? Or, maybe, you are using `gcc` 4.5 in Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm sorry, clang 4.2. I've revised the article, thanks!

Comment: Apple Clang versioning is tied to XCode versioning and different from the actual Clang version. If you do `clang --version` you should get something like "Apple Clang 4.2 based on Clang 3.X" or similar.

Comment: Actually I get "Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)" when I do clang --version. So I guess I'm trying to update the clang instead of degrade it, to support some new c++11 features of this project.

Answer (score 2):

Some might argue this belongs on [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), but I'm not sure C++11 tags grab a lot of attention there:)

Xcode 5.0 is now available from the App Store. Install it, go to Preferences -> Downloads, and install the Command Line Tools. However...

First, you will need to go to Preferences -> Accounts and add your Apple ID. For some reason, the Command Line Tools download requires an account login. I don't know what the rationale for this is.

```
> clang -v
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to build from the command line, using `make` for example (which sounds likely given the project is from Linux), then install [Macports](http://macports.org) and install [whatever version of clang you would like](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=clang):

```
$sudo port install clang-3.1
$sudo clang_select
```

Note that this version of `clang` shouldn't interfere with the Xcode Command Line package if you are will to invoke the Xcode version using `xcrun clang` instead of plain old `clang`.

Comment: Thanks!But how should I switch the version. I tried sudo port install clang_select but it didn't work.